# Why I get an Illegal invocation when invoking from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I been trying to understand this behavior of functions, but I couldn't find the answer.

I was trying to invoke each function of an array of functions. Everything worked fine, but when I put 'prompt' in the array, I got an error:

*Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation*.

To reproduce the error you can try:

```
[prompt][0]()
```

This code will work, I can't explain why neither:

```
[function() { return prompt }][0]()()
```

I know there are a few ways around this to make it work, but I want to understand what's is going on.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `[window.prompt][0].call(window)`

Comment: Thanks,  Rajaprabhu. But could you explain the reason behind this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For background, see [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

The `prompt` function requires that `this` be `window`, which it would be if you called `window.prompt()` or (because `window` is the default context) `prompt()`.

However, when you call `[prompt][0]()`, `this` is the array object.

So the error is not because it is in an array, but because it isn't being called in the context of `window`.

You could pass the context explicitly:

```
[prompt][0].apply(window)
```

Comment: You could also use `bind` on prompt beforehand like this:

`[prompt.bind(window)][0]()`

Comment: A side note on "apply" and "bind": they're pretty weird at first; at least that was the case for me.
Don't be discouraged if you don't completely understand it. I don't think a lot of people who code javascript daily fully understand "bind".

Comment: I would also like to point out that since `apply` isn't being passed an array of arguments, `call` should be used instead.

Comment: @JonathanGray — Why? Aren't they entirely interchangeable if you only pass one argument?

Comment: @Quentin Technically, yes, but `apply` should really only be used in cases where `call` cannot. The former is for when you have unknown arguments in an array and the latter is for when you already explicitly know the arguments. Also if the OP needs to add arguments to the call, the way to do so wouldn't be as obvious using `apply`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `prompt` is a native function, And it expects the `this` inside of it has to be `window`, But when you are extracting it from an array and calling it would make the `this` inside of it as the storage array object. Hence it is illegal and error is appearing.

A sample for you to understand,

```
function test(x){ 
 console.log(this === x) 
}

var x = [test];
x[0](x); //true
```

So from the above code you can understood the `this` inside of function which was extracted out from an array will point the array itself.

There are lot of work around for this, but a most readable one as per my opinion would be using `call`.

```
[prompt][0].call(window) //`this` object of prompt in this would be window.
```